# How can one compute and find the distribution of the areas of the objects in an image with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, area, mahotas

I'd like to get the areas in pixels and the distributions of the different black objects in this image. I assume that with python (openCV or mahotas) it's possible to do it, but I don't know how.

[image]
Can you help me ?

Comment: How do expect the answer to look? A list with one line per black object and the area of it? What do you mean by *"distributions"*?

Comment: I would like the histogram of the different areas of the "dots"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/). It looks like a binary image (0s and 1s) to me, so you could use [regionprops](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) function to get a list of regionprops objects.

Regionprops ignores 0s (which is black in your case), so you might need to invert the image.

Comment: Thks ! that's what I did and it works indeed after being being inverted ! *properties = measure.regionprops(image)
a=[prop.area for prop in properties]
print(a)
a = np.array(a)
plt.hist(np.sqrt(a*0.33/3.14), bins=20)
plt.show()*

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution, given that your question doesn't seem that intent on using any particular tool. It uses **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is readily available for macOS and Windows. You just run the following in a Terminal window:

```
convert blobs.png -threshold 50% -negate     \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true \
   -connected-components 8 info: | awk '/255,255,255/{print $4}'
```

Sample output follows, and it is the size (in pixels) of each blob found in the image:

```
19427
2317
2299
1605
1526
1194
1060
864
840
731
532
411
369
313
288
259
253
244
240
238
216
122
119
90
73
70
36
23
10
```

---

In order to better understand it, remove the `awk` stuff so you can see the output of *"Connected Component Analysis"*:

```
convert blobs.png -threshold 50% -negate -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components 8 info:

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 675x500+0+0 341.1,251.2 301025 srgb(0,0,0)
  13: 198x225+232+119 341.5,227.0 19427 srgb(255,255,255)
  24: 69x62+232+347 269.4,378.9 2317 srgb(255,255,255)
  22: 40x90+67+313 88.8,354.8 2299 srgb(255,255,255)
  20: 55x50+121+278 153.3,299.5 1605 srgb(255,255,255)
  10: 34x82+107+78 126.2,115.5 1526 srgb(255,255,255)
  25: 34x47+439+350 455.4,371.5 1194 srgb(255,255,255)
  16: 26x69+422+183 435.4,217.6 1060 srgb(255,255,255)
  19: 27x44+231+264 243.6,284.1 864 srgb(255,255,255)
  ...
  ...
  21: 5x9+0+284 1.8,288.8 36 srgb(255,255,255)
  29: 6x5+57+467 59.9,468.7 23 srgb(255,255,255)
  4: 6x2+448+0 450.5,0.4 10 srgb(255,255,255)
```

Basically, there is one line of output for each blob. That line tells you the `x,y` position of the top-left corner of the blob and its width and height. It also tells you the centroid, area (in the 4th column which is why I printed `$4` in `awk`) and the colour. Note that your black blobs show up as white (255,255,255) because I inverted your image (with `-negate`) since **ImageMagick** looks for white objects on a black background.

So, if I take the line starting `13:`, and draw in the rectangle containing the blob:

```
convert blobs.png -fill none -stroke red -draw "rectangle 232,119 430,343" result.png
```

[image]